# Ldap shiro authendication without domain suffix

Tags: ldap, shiro, apache-zeppelin

I have configured Ldap with zeppelin with Shiro configuration.now, everything works fine.but, I am able to login with my ldap user with suffix the domain(@company.org).
Is there a possibility to login only with username without suffix.
below is my shiro.ini,

```
    ldapRealm=org.apache.zeppelin.realm.LdapRealm
ldapRealm.contextFactory.systemUsername=cn=hosting,dc=company,dc=org 
ldapRealm.contextFactory.systemPassword=secretpassword
ldapRealm.contextFactory.authenticationMechanism=simple
ldapRealm.contextFactory.url=ldap://ldap.user.base:389
ldapRealm.pagingSize = 200
ldapRealm.authorizationEnabled = true
ldapRealm.searchBase=OU=Users,DC=company,DC=org
ldapRealm.userSearchBase=OU=Users,DC=company,DC=org
ldapRealm.groupSearchBase=OU=Groups,DC=company,DC=org
ldapRealm.memberAttributeValueTemplate=CN={0},OU=Users,DC=company,DC=org
ldapRealm.rolesByGroup = "QC":admin_role
ldapRealm.userLowerCase = true
ldapRealm.groupSearchEnableMatchingRuleInChain = true
```

Answer (score 0):

The "principalSuffix" is in ActiveDirectoryGroupRealm [1] and is not present in LdapRealm [2].

[1] https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/master/zeppelin-server/src/main/java/org/apache/zeppelin/realm/ActiveDirectoryGroupRealm.java

[2] https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/master/zeppelin-server/src/main/java/org/apache/zeppelin/realm/LdapRealm.java